# How to handle utilities for PHP classes in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a list of utility functions for the classes I create inside a composer package. I can autoload the classes easily, but not sure how to setup the utility classes.

My file structure is:

```
composer.json
--src
    --SomeClass.php
    --utilities.php
```

In `utilities.php` I have set up my namespace:

```
namespace PackageName\utilities {
    function functionName() {}
    function functionName2() {}
}
```

then when I load the `utilities` file, I can use the functions like so:

```
use function PackageName\utilities\{functionName, functionName2};

functionName();
```

My issue is that everytime I want to use this `utilities` file, I need to require it and it seems like a bad pattern. I want to use it with the main application that loads this package and also in the classes within the package.

I am more or less fine requiring it in with the class files like in `SomeClass.php`:

```
namespace PackageName;

require_once 'utilities.php';

use PackageName\utilities\functionName;

class SomeClass {
    function methodName() {
      functionName();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to autoload `utilities` somehow with composer either with the parent project or within the `composer.json` of the package?

EDIT: My current `composer.json` file for the package looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "packageauthor/packagename",
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "files: ["src/utilities.php"],
    "psr-0": { "PackageName_": "src },
    "psr-4": { "PackageName\\": "src" }
  }
}
```

and the `composer.json` of my parent project

```
{
  "name": "packageauthor/project",
  ...
  "require": {
    "packageauthor/packagename": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

and in my parent project I have an `index.php` that has

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PackageName\SomeClass;
use function PackageName\utilities\functionName;

new SomeClass(); // works
functionName(); // fatal error
```

I know I can make it work with adding this line to my project composer file:

`"autoload": { "files: ["vendor/packageauthor/packagename/src/utilities.php"] }`

but is there a way my package can use the file without requiring and my project without autoloading the file like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer/PSR - How to autoload functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171078/composer-psr-how-to-autoload-functions)

Comment: Is there any problem with using the autoloader? That's what all this composer stuff is about, and without any hints about where to load the functions from PHP cannot load them

Comment: @NicoHaase not a big problem. I just wondered if there is a better pattern. Because this means in my package class declarations I need to require in the functions file.

Comment: What do you mean with the last sentence?

Comment: I can autoload the `utilities.php` file in the project to use the util funtions, but to use them inside the package classes (the same package where the `utilities.php` file is) I need to require it in. And that seems like a bad pattern.