# Autoloading files with composer that contain no classes just functions

Tags: composer-php, autoload

I am getting crazy.

Is there any way to use composer's autoload functionality to load a file without (!) classes, just containing a namespace with functions, but dynamically?

Imagine a file 1 (Foo.php) in a library which I put into a private composer repository:

```
namespace Foo;

function a() {
//...
}
```

and a file 2 using this library via composer again:

```
require(.../autoload.php);

\Foo\a();
```

I want composer to generate autoload functionality to load the "Foo.php" only if I call a function etc. from it.

But I do not want to wrap Foo.php into a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer/PSR - How to autoload functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171078/composer-psr-how-to-autoload-functions)

Comment: Not really. I want to have the same functionality as with classes: Only load the php file if something from it will be used!

Comment: Currently there is no way to implement autoloading for functions or constants in PHP. This is the best what you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Your desire to autoload functions is logical because may not want to be constrained to OOP, but autoloading could still be efficient.

I believe the problem lies in the built-in PHP autoloader mechanism itself. As @rob006 said, "there is no way to implement autoloading for functions or constants in PHP", but I wanted to see why for myself.

I ran some quick tests and discovered that the [spl_autoload_register()](https://web.archive.org/web/20220131111931/https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function will not call the callback function when an unknown function is called.

Set up the experiment:

```
php > spl_autoload_register(function($class_name){
php (     echo 'Triggered for: '.$class_name;
php ( });
```

Calling a namespaced function does not trigger the echo:

```
php > \test\test();
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test\test() in php shell code:1
```

Calling the `new` operator *does* trigger the echo:

```
php > $test = new \test\test();
Triggered for: test\test
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Class 'test\test' not found in php shell code:1
```

Calling a static function *does* trigger the echo:

```
php > \asdf\adsf::asdf();
Triggered for: asdf\adsf
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Class 'asdf\adsf' not found in php shell code:1
```

`use` does not trigger anything:

```
php > use \test4\test4;
```

So as you can see, it would be difficult to implement in composer because the built-in autoloader in PHP does not make any effort to load functions. The best we can do is to make a wrapper class full of static functions. This is what I did before but I wanted to double check if there was a real solution or an edit that could be made to composer itself.

I did find this interesting Aspect Oriented Programming framework along the way called [GoAOP](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507015115/https://github.com/goaop/framework). It seems to be able to intercept functions but I think it does it by rewriting the code so I don't think it's really an ideal solution to this problem. It was however the only method I could find to intercept functions.

Perhaps we can get function load interception into PHP 9 if we try.