# How to create a utils directory in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a directory for utils in Laravel 8. I have this but it doesn't work:

app/Utils/DateTime.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils\DateTime;

const ISO8601_DATE_FORMAT = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP";  

function parseISO8601(string $time): \DateTime {
    if ($time.endsWith("Z")) {
        $time = $time.str_replace($time, "Z", "+00:00");
    }
    return \DateTime::createFromFormat(ISO8601_DATE_FORMAT, $time);
}
```

app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use function App\Utils\DateTime\parseISO8601 as parseISO8601;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function run(Request $request)
    {
        parseISO8601("2021-10-03T10:00:45.145126+01:00");
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

`Call to undefined function App\Utils\DateTime\parseISO8601()`

What am I missing? It seems that it can't autoload `DateTime` for some reason. Do I need to manually configure an extra path somewhere in Laravel?

Comment: You don't need `as parseISO8601` since you're using the same name. You only need that if you're creating an alias (renaming the function because of name collisions)

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171078/composer-psr-how-to-autoload-functions?

Answer (score 1):

I changed it to a class and restarted PHP. It then gave me an error:

`Class App\Utils\DateTime\DateTime located in ./app/Utils/DateTime.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.` which is explained [here](https://laravelshift.com/knowledge-base/does-not-comply-with-psr-4-autoloading-standard)

I had incorrectly specified the namespace as `App\Utils\DateTime` even though the file was called `DateTime.php`. I just needed to change the namespace to `App\Utils`.