# PHP Composer - autoload functions and constants

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Is it possible to autoload constants or functions with "composer autoload"?

If yes, how do I have to name the files? If I do it the same way as with classes, it is not working.

Example:

Directory Structure

- index.php
- Nested/MyClass.php
- Nested/my_function.php
- Nested/MY_CONSTANT.php

In all three php files in Nested/, this line is present at the beginning

```
namespace Nested;
```

My index.php file looks like the following

```
use Nested\MyClass;
use function Nested\my_function;
use const Nested\MY_CONSTANT;

$t = new MyClass() // Works
my_function(); // Not working
echo MY_CONSTANT // Not working
```

Comment: Please show us the content of all of the mentioned files. Because the construct you mentioned should definitely work.

Comment: "it is not working" - what does that mean?

Comment: An autoloader is made for loading classes. Neither constants nor functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer/PSR - How to autoload functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171078/composer-psr-how-to-autoload-functions)